# Basic laravel auth cannot login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I have id and password, in table account. I'll login with id and password. And the results is bad

auth.php

```
'driver' => 'database',
'model' => 'Pass',
'table' => 'account',
```

models/Pass.php

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Pass extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $table = 'account';
```

PassController.php

```
public function authenticate()
{
$userdata = array( 'id' => Input::get('id'), 'password' => Input::get('password'));
    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
    {
        echo 'oke';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'bad';
    }
}
```

in views

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'PassController@authenticate')) }}
...
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('book/auth', 'PassController@authenticate');
```

How to resolve this? I use laravel 4.2

Comment: Have a look at auth.php inside the config folder. You should change the `user` table to `account` table

Comment: yes, auth.php as above

Comment: Why you are using id & password for login? If you have id, then you can login using following method. It doesnt require password.
Auth::loginUsingId(Input::get('id'));

Comment: id as username and password still password. if username and password match, login succes

Comment: Since your using a model to authenticate you should be using the "eloquent" auth driver

Comment: If the result is 'bad' then its working. Just check your credentials. Is your password Hashed?

Comment: I don't use hash, if use auth::attempt password must hashed? If yes, how to add hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely should, no you basically *have to* store passwords hashed. Having plain text passwords in your db is a major security risk.

Now obviously you need to hash the password when creating a new user. (in your registration controller or something like that).

However to change your existing password manually you can use `artisan tinker` to generate a hash.

```
php artisan tinker
> echo Hash::make('your-secret-password');
```

Then copy the hash and update it in your db.

Also make sure that the password field in your database is at least **60 characters long** otherwise the hash will be truncated.

#### Update

Try this one for testing:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $user = Pass::find(Input::get('id'));
    if(Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password))
    {
        echo 'oke';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'bad';
    }
}
```

#### Update 2

If your hashed password colummn is called `hashed_pass` (or anything else than `password`) you need to specify that in your model:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->hashed_pass;
}
```

Comment: `This way you can just go to the URL /hash/your-secret-password and it will output the hash of that. Then copy it and update it in your db.` This is itself a major security risk. Accessing that will put the password in your plain-text webserver logs (and if you have something like Google Analytics, there as well). Better to use `php artisan tinker` to do this.

Comment: @ceejayoz I was only suggesting this for development. However I clearly forgot to mention that... Will change my answer to `php artisan tinker`. Thanks.

Comment: @lukasgeiter it's possible to see and save the humanic password? For ex: I have colomn password for humanic password and pass_hash for the hashed humanic password.

Comment: You can but shouldn't do that. Password should be stored hashed so even if your database get's compromised the passwords remain uncovered. Is there a reason why you want to do that?

Comment: I will make many username, password and give to user for login to form page, if form submited username and password will be deleted(business role)

Comment: And what's the problem with hashing it?

Comment: oke, back to first question, I have created hashed password, 'driver = eloquent', models with 6 function getXXX, nullable remember_token in table account to but the result is still bad, please give me some solution?

Comment: Okay and you're really logging in by id? so your credentials are like `1` and `password`?

Comment: yes, but if there is an easier way and simple, can change it

Comment: Nono I was just making sure. I updated my answer with some code. Can you test that?

Comment: It work if I create new table just id, hashed pass, remember_token, and in old table is id, password, hashed pass, remember_token. Can explain this?

Comment: Is the db field not called `password`? If so, you need to change that in your model. See the updated answer...